# Querying ProcessState

Tags: go, process, status

I have a simple program and runs an exe and checks the Exited value afterwards, but it is giving me an "panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference" error, any idea why?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    prog:= exec.Command("path\to\exe")
    prog.Dir = "path\to"
    go prog.Run()
    fmt.Println(prog.ProcessState.Exited())
    time.Sleep(500 * time.Second)
}
```

Comment: The posted code does not compile. Perhaps you meant to use / instead of \ in the string literals.

Comment: \\ actually, it's on Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation says](https://godoc.org/os/exec#Cmd.ProcessState):

> ProcessState contains information about an exited process available after a call to Wait or Run.

The main goroutine accesses the ProcessState field before the field is set to a non-nil value by the call to Run() in the goroutine.  The call to Exited() panics as a result.

A simple fix is to call Run() from the main goroutine.

Comment: Thanks, that is explanatory. If I understand correctly, ProcessState is populated only after the processs has Exited? Wouldn't Exited() evaluate to true all the time?                I have a Gin webserver app (https://github.com/wys35/GoAPIserver) that is listening on 8080 and thus would not return. What I intend to do is to make the process run as a service (https://github.com/kardianos/service/blob/master/example/runner/runner.go), what is strange is on line 98, it evaluates to true even when I can see my exe running in task manager. Do you have idea about this?

Comment: On some operating systems, Exited() returns true only if the process exited normally.  Exited() returns false if the process was terminated by a signal and other condition. I cannot help with the Windows specific questions as I have not used Windows in many years.

Comment: Thanks all the same.